# Excluding a folder from war file after mvn clean install command(building project)

Tags: maven

I have a folder(e.g-app) inside webapp folder.
I want to exclude app folder while creating the war file.
I have tried with the following tags in the pom file:

```
<warSourceExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/app/**</warSourceExcludes>
            <packagingExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/app/**</packagingExcludes>
```

Any help..Most welcome  :)

Comment: Just remove it from there? What kind of App?

Comment: Its a normal folder that contains ui related files(js,html etc).I just don't want that folder in my war file as it's minified version is already getting created AND  it is there inside the war.

Comment: Than remove them from the above location if you correctly configured the minifiaction process it will work correctly.

Comment: Problem is its including minified folder and original folder as well.
But I don't want that original folder in my war file.